# An item with the same key has already been added. Key: Id when trying to insert using stored procedure in .NET

Tags: sql, asp.net-core, stored-procedures, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to implement a method that executes a stored procedure in a `foreach` loop using and I keep getting an error that says

> An item with the same key has already been added. Key: StudentId

Controller:

```
[HttpPost("{id}/link-to-subjects")]
public async Task<ActionResult> LinkStudentToSubjects(int id, int[] subjectIds)
{
    try
    {
        await _studentRepository.LinkStudentToSubjectsAsync(id, subjectIds);
    
        return NoContent();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return BadRequest(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Repository method that calls the stored procedure:

```
public async Task<bool> LinkStudentToSubjectsAsync(int studentId, int[] subjectIds)
{
    DeleteSubjectStudentLinks(studentId);

    var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    foreach (var subjectId in subjectIds)
    {
        parameters.Add(StoredProcedures.Params.StudentId, studentId);
        parameters.Add(StoredProcedures.Params.SubjectId, subjectId);
               
        linkResult = await _repository.ExecuteStoredProcAsync<StudentSubject>(StoredProcedures.LinkStudentSubjects, parameters);
    }

    if (linkResult is not null)
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Stored procedure:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[LinkStudentSubjects] 
    @StudentSubjectID int,
    @StudentID int,
    @SubjectID int
AS
    DECLARE @ID int
    DECLARE @TableTestID TABLE (ID int)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @TableStudentSubjectID TABLE (ID int)

    -- IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT StudentID , SubjectID FROM [dbo].[StudentSubjects]
    --                WHERE StudentID = @StudentID)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [dbo].[StudentSubjects] (StudentId, SubjectId)
        OUTPUT inserted.id INTO @TableStudentSubjectID(ID)
        VALUES (@StudentID, @SubjectID)

        SELECT ID FROM @TableStudentSubjectID
    END
END
```

Comment: unrelated: your proc LinkStudentSubjects is NOT transaction safe: https://sqlperformance.com/2020/09/locking/upsert-anti-pattern  Also: looping from code like that will have poor performance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code from

```
public async Task<bool> LinkStudentToSubjectsAsync(int studentId, int[] subjectIds)
{
    DeleteSubjectStudentLinks(studentId);
    var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    foreach (var subjectId in subjectIds)
    {
        parameters.Add(StoredProcedures.Params.StudentId, studentId);
        parameters.Add(StoredProcedures.Params.SubjectId, subjectId);
           
        linkResult = await _repository.ExecuteStoredProcAsync<StudentSubject>(StoredProcedures.LinkStudentSubjects, parameters);
    }
    if (linkResult is not null)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

to

```
public async Task<bool> LinkStudentToSubjectsAsync(int studentId, int[] subjectIds)
{
    DeleteSubjectStudentLinks(studentId);
    var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    foreach (var subjectId in subjectIds)
    {
        parameters.Clear();
        parameters.Add(StoredProcedures.Params.StudentId, studentId);
        parameters.Add(StoredProcedures.Params.SubjectId, subjectId);

        linkResult = await _repository.ExecuteStoredProcAsync<StudentSubject>(StoredProcedures.LinkStudentSubjects, parameters);
    }

    if (linkResult is not null)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

**Reason**

The `new Dictionary<string, object>();` you defined is outside the foreach loop, so after the first execution, the previous `studentId` will exist in the dictionary. The solution to this problem is to clear the previous record before executing the stored procedure or define `new Dictionary` in the loop.

Comment: Or even better: **define** the parameters **once** outside the `foreach` loop, and only set their values inside the `foreach` loop - no point in re-creating the parameter definitions over and over and over again ....